# Checkerboard using arrays and object oriented programming

Tags: java, arrays, string, draw

Driver Class:

```
    //Objective: make a 10X10 Grid appear
    //it should be a red and white or black and white 
    //checkerboard.

    public Checkers()
    {
        con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        for (int xDimension = 0; xDimension<theGrid.length; xDimension++)
        {
            for (int yDimension = 0; yDimension< theGrid[xDimension].length; yDimension++)
            {
                theGrid[xDimension][yDimension] = new Block(xDimension,yDimension);
            }
        }

        //pass in the row and column numbers to the constructor
        //these will define where the Blocks appear.
        t.start();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }



    public void paint(Graphics gr)
    {
        Image i=createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)i.getGraphics();
        for (int x = 0; x < theGrid.length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < theGrid[x].length; y++)
            {
                theGrid[x][y].draw(g2);
            }
        }
        g2.dispose();
        gr.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Block Class:

```
public class Block
{
    private int x, y, width, height, rowNum, colNum;
    private Color color;


    public Block(int xDimension, int yDimension)
    {
        Random ra = new Random();
        xDimension = rowNum;
        yDimension = colNum;
        //finish

    public void draw(Graphics2D gt)
    {
        // put your code here

        if (rowNum % 2 == 0)
        {

            if (colNum % 2 == 0)
            {
                gt.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
                gt.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
            else if (colNum % 2 == 1)
            {
                gt.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
                gt.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        else if (rowNum % 2 == 1)
        {

            if (colNum % 2 == 0)
            {
                gt.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
                gt.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (colNum % 2 == 1)
            {
                gt.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
                gt.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
        //Red/Black/white color.
        gt.drawString("R:"+rowNum+", C:"+colNum, x+3, y +3);
    }

    public void getLocation()
    {
    }

}
```

For programming, we're making a checkerboard using code our teacher has made but we have to fill in the rest.  He left instructions via //.  The gist of this assigment is to program a checkerboard, (with alternating colors, every other block is red) and within the block, it lets you know what row and column the block is located in.  I'm having difficulty simply getting my program to show up and I can't pinpoint my problem.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have

```
if (rowNum % 2 == 0) 
...
else if (rowNum % 2 == 0)
```

in the draw method in Block.java?

Maybe you mean the second one to be

```
else if (rowNum % 2 == 1)
```

That might fix your problems.

Comment: I was messing with my code and I guess I overlooked that.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to stack overflow too, but just a heads up: people here don't like to read through all your code and do your homework for you.  You're supposed to get a start and then ask a specific question about an issue you have, not just say that it doesn't work and ask people to write it for you. Try looking through your lecture notes and course references before asking a question here. That being said, I'll try to get you started.

First, you need to finish your block class.  In the constructor, you give it 2 parameters, but never use them.  To fix this, your code should probably say:

```
public Block(int xDimension, int yDimension)
{
    rowNum = xDimension;
    colNum = yDimension;
    //finish
}
```

When you call this constructor in the code, you should say:

```
    theGrid[xDimension][yDimension] = new Block(xDimension, yDimension);
```

This will tell the block where it is on the board.  You will also need to set the x and y for each block as well as the width and height.  There is a lot left for you to fill out, but my guess is that your professor has given you some references so you're not totally in the dark.  If you're really baffled, there are always office hours as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Our teacher teaches class almost like a college environment(I'm a high school freshman by the way) so I have zero notes and no textbook for reference:( and since this is something (2D arrays) I had never done before, I couldnt reference old code either.  I had no idea what was important and what wasn't so...I just put everything